# Is the set of all context-free languages contained in the set of all languages that have a w-grammar?

Tags: context-free

Word grammar (w-grammar) is a context free grammar in which all laws are of the following forms:

$A \rightarrow B, A \rightarrow \epsilon, A \rightarrow w_1B, A \rightarrow Bw_2$

$A, B \in N$ (nonterminal), $w_i \in \Sigma^\ast$

$ L_{w-grammar} $ - set of all languages that have a w-grammar

$ L_{CFG} $ - set of all languages that have a context free grammar

Is the following statement is true $ L_{CFG} \subseteq L_{w-grammar} $ ?

Answer (score 1):

The class of languages accepted by this kind of grammar is known as [linear languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar) (the definition on Wikipedia is slightly different, but equivalent). According to Wikipedia, the language of all balanced parentheses (generated by $S \to SS \mid (S) \mid \epsilon$) is context-free but not linear.